# pyspark Py4J error using canopy :PythonAccumulatorV2([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, canopy

I installed canopy IDE on windows as well as python and pyspark. When executing the code of a program, there was problem of a sparK Context:

```
findspark.init()
conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('MonEssai')
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
lines = sc.textFile("file:///PremiéreEssai/ file9.txt")
fun = lines.flatMap(listsGraph)
results =fun.collect()

for result1 in results:
  if(result1): 
    if ((result1[0].strip().startswith("sub_"))|(result1[0].strip().startswith("start"))):
      for k in range(0,len(result1)):
           if result1[k] not in Loc: 
                Loc.append(result1[k])
    else :
        for j in range(0,len(result1)):
           if result1[j] not in Ext: 
                Ext.append(result1[j])

result3 = sc.parallelize(Ext)
ExtSimilarity= result3.map(MatchExt).filter(lambda x: x != None).collect() 
#print(ExtSimilarity)         

#print(Loc)
result3 = sc.parallelize(Loc)
result9= result3.map(pos_debut)
result11= result9.map(opcode)
VectOpcode= result11.flatMapValues(f).flatMap(lambda X: [((X[0],len(X[1])))]).groupByKey().mapValues(list)
VectOpcode2 = VectOpcode.collect()
```

And I got the following error:

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Constructor
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class
>   java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String])
>   does not exist

```
Py4JErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
C:\Premi�reEssai\maman.py in <module>()
    818 findspark.init()
    819 conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('MonEssai')
--> 820 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
    821 lines = sc.textFile("file:///PremiéreEssai/ file9.txt")
    822 fun = lines.flatMap(listsGraph)
C:\Users\hene\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.pyc in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    347         with SparkContext._lock:
    348             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 349                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    350             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    351 
C:\Users\hene\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:
C:\Users\hene\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.pyc in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    187         self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server(auth_token)
    188         (host, port) = self._accumulatorServer.server_address
--> 189         self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port, auth_token)
    190         self._jsc.sc().register(self._javaAccumulator)
    191 
C:\Users\hene\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:
C:\Users\hene\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
--> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333         else:
    334             raise Py4JError(
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String]) does not exist
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So, I'm stuck in this what should I do?

Answer (score 6):

While my setup is different, I just had the exact same error an hour ago. The problem I had is pyspark version is differnt from the spark version. You can run `pip list` to check your pyspark version.

Answer (score 2):

Same error was coming for me also. Then I have instlled Spark with 2.4.4 as same as PySpark version 2.4.4. 
Issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

Setting a environment variable called PYTHONPATH = {hadoop_path}/python would help